# How to seize a Hobbit thief who stole the one of a kind de Broglie's suit?

Tags: technology, magic

A de Broglie's suit grants the user the following miracles:

̶1̶.̶ ̶A̶m̶p̶l̶i̶f̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶m̶a̶t̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶w̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶e̶x̶p̶o̶n̶e̶n̶t̶i̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶t̶i̶m̶e̶ ̶u̶p̶o̶n̶ ̶a̶c̶t̶i̶v̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶,̶ ̶q̶u̶a̶n̶t̶u̶m̶ ̶m̶e̶c̶h̶a̶n̶i̶c̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶s̶p̶e̶a̶k̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶r̶e̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶q̶u̶a̶n̶t̶u̶m̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶t̶i̶c̶l̶e̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶l̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶t̶a̶i̶n̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶p̶h̶y̶s̶i̶c̶a̶l̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶p̶e̶r̶t̶i̶e̶s̶.̶ ̶(̶P̶o̶w̶e̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶t̶i̶c̶u̶l̶a̶r̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶o̶s̶e̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶i̶n̶d̶o̶m̶i̶t̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶s̶u̶c̶h̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶ ̶H̶o̶b̶b̶i̶t̶.̶)̶ ̶

2̶.̶ ̶A̶c̶t̶u̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶u̶n̶i̶q̶u̶e̶ ̶s̶u̶i̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶k̶n̶i̶t̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶S̶c̶h̶r̶o̶d̶i̶n̶g̶e̶r̶'̶s̶ ̶c̶a̶t̶ ̶f̶u̶r̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶c̶h̶ ̶g̶i̶v̶e̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶u̶i̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶b̶i̶l̶i̶t̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶ ̶i̶t̶s̶ ̶s̶u̶p̶e̶r̶p̶o̶s̶i̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶e̶s̶,̶ ̶m̶e̶a̶n̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶u̶i̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶i̶m̶p̶l̶y̶ ̶a̶w̶e̶s̶o̶m̶e̶!̶

3. Super strength. This suits absorbs all the kinetic energy coming from the metabolism of all multicellular organisms with an effective range of radius 42.195 km. (Power steal is 10000 Watts and the suit can discharge at max one million Ampere at room temperature, victims are left for dead.)

How do the modern police or military capture this thief alive to face the trial while keeping casualty to a minimum? The thief Hobbit plots to assassinate the new world leader on the fateful day but assuming we have to stop it.

Special note: this suit can manipulate gravitational waves to leech its unfortunate victims' power.

Comment: I intentionally removed point 1 and 2 so as to do humanity a favor :)

Comment: If this were a question about your handwavium-based plot device, this could be on-topic. As is, however, you're asking about the plot of your story, rather than the world it occurs in, and is thus off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

## Use Rosie Cotton as a Honey Trap

[image]

She should be able to part the thieving Hobbit from his armour.

Comment: Looks like a joke, but attacking when the target is sleeping, having sex, washing himself, in the toilet or otherwise totally helpless is the normal solution. And it would totally work on armor. If you are in a hurry using chemical weapons to make the target incapacitated right **now** should be an option.

Comment: @VilleNiemi - It's no joke.  Honey Traps have been used for centuries as a way of disarming an opponent.

Comment: I know. The key term was **looks like**.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out where the thief is going to be or set up a trap in a location that can easily lure in the thief.  Rig the area with a trap that will release a massive amount of sleeping gas or some other crippling toxin.  Wait till thief is rendered unconscious and proceed to recover the thief.

This assumes the armor is not constantly draining kinetic energy, if it is then you will need a different to take out the armor before recovering it.  If it absorbs only kinetic based energy then hit with thermal based energy, until the armor's capabilities shutdown.  Unfortunately this could result in a cooked thief depending on how well the armor protects him or her.

If possible consult with the manufacturer or the user manual for the armor to find out about known limitations or defects with the armor and exploit those weaknesses.